# Touchscreen compatible Terminal for Ubuntu Mate

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen, software-recommendation

I have Ubuntu Mate installed on my Pi and I'm pretty happy with it, no problems. **However,** the built-in terminal application is definitely not designed for touch screens, nor the file browser or any other built-in app. What I mean is, for example, I can't swipe. I have to use the scroll bar. This is not the case for Chromium, which isn't built in.

Are there any terminals out there that can be used with a touch screen? Also, I would be really happy if you provide replacements for other built-in apps.

By the way, my touch screen is WaveShare 7-inch 800x480 Touchscreen.

Comment: I assume by terminal application you mean the command shell terminal window with the keyboard interface where you type in commands? What behavior do you expect from a touchscreen compatible terminal application?

Comment: My Raspberry Pi isn't with me right now. I will add a gif when I have it.

Comment: A gif of your raspberry pi setup will not explain the actual application behavior you are wanting to see. Right now your question is vague and not something that I could answer. Are you expecting a user experience similar to a smart phone user interface such as Android or Apple?

Comment: @RichardChambers Yes, kind of.

Comment: If you want the user experience of an Android phone then you need to use an Android phone and not a Raspberry Pi. Or you could try running Android on a Raspberry Pi. It appears that people have done so https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/android-raspberry-pi/  Raspbian, and I assume you are using Raspbian, is more geared towards embedded and using the Pi in a IoT application rather than a general purpose smart phone type of application.

Comment: I guess I can't explain. I don't want a mobile OS (android, ios, etc.) or such, I have Ubuntu Mate 16.XX LTS, and I just want to scroll without using the scroll bar, just like in any iOS or Android browser, by **swiping**. Chromium has built-in support for touch screens whereas in terminal, I have to use the scroll bar because when I try to swipe, I select the text instead.